# how to use a variable in a for loop outside the loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

when I put the proxy variable inside the for loop the code work fine, but when I print proxy outside the for loop it only give the first loop and stops, is there a way the proxy variable work fine if i used it outside the for loop.

```
value = ['3128', '3128', '3128', '3128']
num = ['40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143']
for (a, c) in zip(num,value):
    proxy = a+':'+c
        print(proxy)
```

to explain what am doing, am doing a shoe bot that open multiple windows at the same time and each window has its own unique proxy, I want to put the proxy variable in the function get_chromedriver as a parameter.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
import time
import zipfile

    proxy_host = ['40.122.24.111', '40.122.24.111', '40.122.24.111', '40.122.24.111']  # rotating proxy
    proxy_port = ['3128', '3128', '3128', '3128']
    proxy_username = ['lukmanaraby', 'lukmanaraby', 'lukmanaraby', 'lukmanaraby']
    proxy_password = ['aiobotagents', 'aiobotagents', 'aiobotagents', 'aiobotagents']
 for (a, c) in zip(proxy_host,proxy_port):
        proxy = a+':'+c
 
    
    def test_logic():
        url = 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/'
        webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options).get(url)
        # Implement your test logic
    def auth_json(host,port,user,password):
        global manifest_json
        global background_js
        manifest_json  = """
    {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Chrome Proxy",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
    }
    """
    
        background_js = """
    var config = {
            mode: "fixed_servers",
            rules: {
              singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: "%s",
                port: parseInt(%s)
              },
              bypassList: ["localhost"]
            }
          };
    
    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});
    
    function callbackFn(details) {
        return {
            authCredentials: {
                username: "%s",
                password: "%s"
            }
        };
    }
    
    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                callbackFn,
                {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                ['blocking']
    );
    """ % (host,port,user,password)
    
    
        #containing the authentication of the proxies.
    def proxy_auth(): #transfering the information of the proxies to auth_json function
     for (i,j,m,k) in zip(proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_username, proxy_password):
        auth_json(i,j,m,k)
    def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=proxy):
        global  chrome_options
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        if use_proxy:
            pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'
    
            with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
                zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
                zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
            chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
        if user_agent==proxy:
            chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % user_agent)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options)
        return driver
    
    N = 5   # Number of browsers to spawn
    thread_list = list()
    
    # Start test
    for i in proxy_host:
        get_chromedriver()
        proxy_auth()
        t = threading.Thread(name='Test {}'.format(i), target=test_logic)
        t.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        print (t.name + ' started!')
        thread_list.append(t)
    
    # Wait for all thre<ads to complete
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()
    
    print ('Test completed!')
        enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no way I can think of to make it work while keeping variable type the same as it is right now (str). If assigned a value inside a `for` loop and accessed outside the loop it will only hold the last value it was assigned before the loop terminated.

The best way to do it is to create a list variable and append values to the list inside the loop. After that all values can be easily accessed from the resulting list:

```
value = ['3128', '3128', '3128', '3128']
num = ['40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143']
proxy = []
for (a, c) in zip(num,value):
    proxy.append(a+':'+c)

for item in proxy:
    print(item)
```

**Updated as per comments below:**
To use resulting variable in a function without assigning values to a list you can just put the function call inside the `for` loop.

```
def my_func(a):
   return a

value = ['3128', '3128', '3128', '3128']
num = ['40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143', '40.69.144.143']

for (a, c) in zip(num,value):
    proxy.append(a+':'+c)
    foo = my_func(proxy)
```

**EDIT 2:**
So I had a look at your function and it seems like and easy fix to modify it to use lists instead of simple strings. This way the function will return a list of multiple drivers based on multiple proxies:

```
    def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent: list = proxy):
        global  chrome_options
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        if use_proxy:
            pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'
    
            with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
                zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
                zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
            chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
        drivers = []
        for i in user_agent:
            chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % user_agent)
            drivers.append(webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options))
        return drivers
```

Comment: sorry, but this solution don't help at all, what I want to do is to put the variable that was used in the for loop into a function, thank u for sharing <3

Comment: So why can't your function work with a list? Alternatively, put your function call inside the `for` loop.

Comment: am sorry am still a beginner in programming,but the function already in a for loop            edit:I will post the whole code

Comment: @TahaDaboussi, I amended my answer with a different approach.

Comment: really appreciate the help, been stuck in this problem for multiple days thank u